# Dynamic JPA OR Expression

Tags: jpa

How can I construct Criteria Query to update status of multiple items?

```
final CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaUpdate<Item> query = builder.createCriteriaUpdate(Item.class);
Root<Item> root = query.from(Item.class);
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
for(Long id : itemIds) 
{
    predicates.add(builder.or(builder.equal(root.get(Item_.id), id)));
}

query.set(root.get(Item_.status), status)
    .where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));

entityManager.createQuery(query).executeUpdate();
```

The above query only work if itemIds. size() == 1. If the itemIds.size()  > 2 then the entities will not be updated. Can anyone help to construct correct predicate for OR expression please.

Thank in advance!

Comment: why not give people a clue about what you're trying to achieve with the WHERE clause? What is the JPQL that it equates to? What SQL is generated?

Comment: Neil, thank for giving me advise of constructing better question. I wanted to convert the query "Update Item Set Item.status = :status Where Item.id = :id_1 or Item.id = :id_2" to Criteria. After doing couple hours of research, I was able to achieve it. Thank for the advise, cheers!